# how use range created with address function

Tags: excel

I write below code in G18:

```
=ADDRESS(2,1)&":"&ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/((A:A<>"")*(A:A<>0)),ROW(A:A)),1)
```

that return

```
$A$2:$A$26
```

How can use that for define a range and use it in ListFillRange?

Answer (score 0):

Just refers to the value in cell G18. Something like this:

```
Sub SubExample()
    
    With Worksheets(1)
        Set lb = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlListBox, 100, 10, 100, 100)
        lb.ControlFormat.ListFillRange = Range("G18").Value
    End With

End Sub
```